# Test if a variable is defined, if not, assign it an empty string in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, conditional-statements

Here is my coffeescript code:

```
if c.urls.voice then c.urls.voice else ""
```

Does anyone have any ideas about whether there is a better way to write this code in Coffeescript?

Comment: In that code, *voice* isn't a variable, it's an Object property. The test is if it's falsey, so will set the value to empty string if its current value is `0`, `false`, `null`, `NaN`, and so on, not just *undefined*.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) to assign to a non-existing variable/property:

```
c.urls.voice ?= ""
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to assign it but only access with a default value, use the `or` (or `||`) operator:

```
… = c.urls.voice or "" // equivalent to your if statement
```

however I guess you're even here actually looking for the existential operator which specifically checks for `null` and `undefined` values, not all falsy ones:

```
… = c.urls.voice ? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for me:

```
c.urls.voice ? ""
```

which will compiles into:

```
var _ref;

if ((_ref = c.urls.voice) != null) {
  _ref;
} else {
  "";
};
```